# Check if no records exist in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Okay so I've hit a wall for some reason and I can't figure this out. I wan't to check if there are any records in a query and then use an @if in my view to say either "yes, there are records" or "none". Nothing I've tried is working..

What I want:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-style">
    <h1 class="no-border">YOUR LATEST CONVERSIONS</h1>
        @if(something here that lets me test if $transactions is empty)
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Result</th>
                <th>Result Value</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($transactions as $transaction)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->status }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->amount }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->value }}</td>
                    <td>{{ number_format($transaction->result, 2) }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->result_value }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $transaction->created_at }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        @else
            yo no records
        @endif
</div>
```

My controller:

```
public function index($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
    $id = $user->id;

    $transactions = Transactions::where('user_id', '=', $id)->take(5)->get();

    return view('user.profile', compact('user', '=', 'userCurrency', 'transactions'));
```

So if you see in the top part there's a basic @if. Maybe I'm over thinking it, or am I passing in something that cant be checked the way I want it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is as easy as:

```
@if(count($transactions) > 0)
```

Comment: I blame the fact it's late at night. I actually did try that and I was pulling my hair out wondering why it wasn't working. I just tried again and it did, so I must have done something wrong before. Aaaah! Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: that happens sometimes :) good luck with your transactions ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
@if (!$transactions->isEmpty())
...
@endif
```

this use laravel collection method do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`@if($transactions)` should do the trick.